# Html/Css - Scaling svg by percentage

Tags: html, css, svg

I have svgs file defined by the following:

> svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="38.025pt" height="10.102pt" viewBox="0 0 38.025 10.102" version="1.2"

This tells me that the svg base dimensions are 38.025pt x 10.102pt. How can I insert this svg image into html code so that 100% width translates to 38.025pt without having to write the svg's dimensions manually every single times?(and if I want the svg twice as big, I would only swap 100% by 200%)

Comment: simply remove the width/height attribute and the SVG will scale in width based on the container and the height will follow to keep the ratio

Comment: But how do I specify the container dimensions?

Comment: You should read this article: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ . Everything about svg and scaling reunited in one place.

Comment: can you give a concrete example where you are setting the dimension and you want instead to use percentage?

Comment: For the cause, let's pretend it is a very barebone html with a <div> element that contains an <img>